# How to launch a custom URI from an extension without leaving an empty tab open?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that opens a custom URI (that will then open a registered protocol URI in another application that is registered to the system).

For example, my custom protocol URI is `mycustomapp://input-arguments-here`

If I create an HTML page with an anchor `<a href="mycustomapp://input-arguments-here">Link</a>` this opens my custom app with the `input-arguments-here` as expected.

I have created a Chrome extension to open my custom URI.

```
function openCustomURIScheme(info, tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
      url: "mycustomapp:/" + info.linkUrl
    },
    function(newTab) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        chrome.tabs.remove(newTab.id);
      }, 250);
    }
  );
}
```

In Firefox, this works great. It opens the dialog box that prompts the user to "Open" the extension. Meanwhile, it closes the blank tab that opened when we created the tab to go to the custom URI.

In Chrome, this does not work. When the `chrome.tabs.remove(newTab.id)` is called, it closes the tab *and* the prompt to open the link in the external application.

If I omit this:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    chrome.tabs.remove(newTab.id);
  }, 250);
```

It works but then I get an empty tab that remains every time I launch a custom URI.

How can I open the custom URI from a chrome extension without leaving a blank tab window behind?

Comment: Try appending such a link element in the background page DOM and then .click() it.

Comment: That sounds like it would work... Trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: I tried `  var a=document.createElement("a"); 
  document.body.appendChild(a); 
  a.id="somelinkid";
  a.href = info.linkUrl;
  document.getElementById('somelinkid').click();` but it didn't work. when you use a background page, it can't have a background script right?

Comment: "when you use a background page, it can't have a background script right?" - It certainly can.

Comment: OK it wasn't working unless I added a `target="_blank"` but then i'm back with the same problem I started with

Comment: Try also adding an `iframe` element with `name` attribute like `foo` so you can set your link's `target` attribute to this `foo` as well.

Comment: that makes chrome mad. it crashes it.

Comment: same thing happens when you try to append an iframe with a `src` set to a custom URI. crashes instantly

Comment: i'm going to create a ticket on the issue tracker. feels like this is a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I worked around the problem.

I created an "on installed" handler that tells the shows an HTML upon installing the extension that will instruct the user to click a link to the custom URI and tells them to click the "always" checkbox on the custom URI so that it from future doesn't prompt them.

Something like:

> In order to complete the installation, click on this link below, then
>   when prompted select "always open links in custom-app-here".

Then at that point the existing solution where it opens it in the tab, then closes the tab after a small ms delay works just like it does on firefox because there is no more prompt.